# How I can find parent and child from self reference table.?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my table's (emp_details) content. emp_id is "primary key" and emp_man_id is "foreign key" with references to emp_detais(emp_id)

self reference table:

```
emp_id    emp_name  emp_place  emp_man_name    emp_man_id
    1     arun      klm        arun  
    2     nivin     thr        arun             1
    3     vinay     ekm        arun             1
    4     ajo       plk        nivin            2
    5     alan      knr        nivin            2
    6     ravi      tvm        vinay            3
    7     vipin     mlp        vinay            3
    8     ani       ksd        ajo              4
    9     vino      pta        ajo              4
    11    sarat     wyd        alan             5
    10    siva      alp        alan             5
```

I need to write a function for this table, if I pass the value 10 as employee id;

I need output like

```
emp_id emp_man_id
  10         5
  5          2
  2          1
```

This is the function I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_e1(IN id integer) 
  RETURNS TABLE(em_id integer, emp_mid integer) 
AS 
$BODY$ 
begin 

  return query 
    with recursive d as ( 
       select emp_id, emp_man_id, 0 as level 
       from emp_details 
       where emp_id = id 
       UNION ALL 
       select c.emp_id, c.emp_man_id, level+1 
       from d 
         inner join emp_details c on c.emp_man_id = d.emp_id 
    ) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM d; 
  end; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Show us your query and describe what's wrong with it!

Comment: What SQL are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.? And can you clarify the columns in your table data, because it is totally unclear

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_e1(IN id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(em_id integer, emp_mid integer) AS
$BODY$
 begin
 return query
 with recursive d as (
   select emp_id, emp_man_id, 0 as level 
    from emp_details
    where emp_id = id
  UNION ALL
   select c.emp_id, c.emp_man_id, level+1
    from d inner join emp_details c on c.emp_man_id = d.emp_id
 )
 SELECT * FROM d;
 end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: if i pass employee id as 11 i need all the manegers up to top level

Comment: there are 5 columns in my table ...

Comment: emp_id ,emp_name, emp_place, emp_man_name ,emp_man_id..

Comment: Don't post additional information as comments. **Edit** your question. So what is wrong with the function you have? What is the error you get?

Comment: @Isac, please accept my apologize, believe me I didn't know your question is about postgresql I thought it's for mssql server, I seen sqlserver mentioned under the question and now I'm not seeing it (maybe I was wrong) that's why my answer was for sqlserver. anyway I hope you'll get it fixed soon. good luck.

Answer (score 3):

(**EDIT:** answer was before editing the question and adding `postgresql` tag to it, in comments under question at the first the `SQL Server` has been mentioned(am not sure maybe I didn't notice well and I was wrong), that's why the answer first provided for `MS SQL Server` however the `postgresql` form of the query is also added immediately after edit of question and adding postgresql tag to it.)

---

*(for MS SQL Server)*

use a `recursive cte`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn(@empId int)
RETURNS @t table (empid int, manid int)
as
begin

with cte (empid, manid) as
(
  select emp_id,man_id
  from emp where emp_id=@empId
  union all
  select e.emp_id, e.man_id
  from emp e 
  join cte on e.emp_id=cte.manid
)
insert into @t
select * from cte;
return
end
```

a [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c948/6)

---

*(for Postgresql)*

with `PostgreSQL` just add the `recursive` keyword before `cte` and change the function format to Posgres format.

```
with recursive cte (empid, manid) as
(
  select emp_id,man_id
  from emp where emp_id=10
  union all
  select e.emp_id, e.man_id
  from emp e 
  join cte on e.emp_id=cte.manid
)
select * from cte
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6c948/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      emp_id INT ,
      emp_man_id INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, NULL ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 1 ),
        ( 4, 2 ),
        ( 5, 2 ),
        ( 6, 3 ),
        ( 7, 3 ),
        ( 8, 4 ),
        ( 9, 4 ),
        ( 11, 5 ),
        ( 10, 5 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   emp_id ,
                        emp_man_id
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    emp_id = 10
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.emp_id ,
                        t.emp_man_id
               FROM     @t t
                        JOIN cte c ON t.emp_id = c.emp_man_id
               WHERE    t.emp_man_id IS NOT NULL
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
```

Output:

```
emp_id  emp_man_id
10      5
5       2
2       1
```

Wrap into function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test ( @id INT )
RETURNS @t TABLE
    (
      emp_id INT ,
      emp_man_id INT
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        WITH    cte
                  AS ( SELECT   emp_id ,
                                emp_man_id
                       FROM     TableName
                       WHERE    emp_id = @id
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT   t.emp_id ,
                                t.emp_man_id
                       FROM     TableName t
                                JOIN cte c ON t.emp_id = c.emp_man_id
                       WHERE    t.emp_man_id IS NOT NULL
                     )
            INSERT  INTO @t
                    ( emp_id, emp_man_id )
                    SELECT  emp_id ,
                            emp_man_id
                    FROM    cte

        RETURN    
    END
```

Comment: Its not working is not an answer. What is not working? Did you change TableName to your table name?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, the OP first mentioned SQL Server, yes do you remember!?

Comment: @Farhęg, yes I remember that :)

Comment: The CTE [works in Postgres](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d1469/1) if you add the mandatory (by the SQL standard) `recursive` keyword. The temp-table and the function however are SQL Server specific

Answer (score 0):

If you need manager's data I suggest you to use this solution (in **SQL Server**):

1. Create a function to gather parents like a path (`..\..\..\`)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AllParents ( @emp_id int )
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @result varchar(max), @emp_man_id int

    Set @emp_man_id = (Select emp_man_id from temptable where emp_id = @emp_id)

    --if you need also a function for finding children it will be same:
    --Set @emp_man_id = (Select emp_id from temptable where emp_man_id = @emp_id)

    if (@emp_man_id is Null)
        set @result = ''
    else
        set @result = dbo.AllParents(@emp_man_id) + '\' + cast(@emp_man_id as varchar(max)) + '#'

    return @result
END
GO
```

2. Use it to get your results like this (example for `10`):

```
select * from temptable
where dbo.AllParents(10) like '%\' + cast(emp_id as varchar(max)) + '#%'
```

But results of above query is not that you shown, But I think is that you want - It's All data of all managers to most top level-.

If you also want to have data of `emp_id = 10` you can add it to where like this:

```
or emp_id = 10
```

If you also add a children function add it to where like this

```
or dbo.AllChildren(10) like '%\' + cast(emp_id as varchar(max)) + '#%'
```

Note: For sorting managers you can also use below `order by` :

```
order by len(dbo.AllParents(emp_id))
```

Note: If you also need to show the path use the function as a field like below:

```
select *, replace(dbo.AllParents(emp_id), '#', '') from temptable
```